# How to use <mvc:view-controller /> in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC to build my application.
I want to show a default jsp  when user runs the application in the browser. I don't want to use `<welcome-file>` tag in the web.xml.

I guess I can use

```
 <mvc:view-controller />
```

I have created a folder and added search.jsp as follows
 WEB-INF/views/search.jsp

Following is the sample spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans ...>
      <context:component-scan
        base-package="org.lacare.frc.controller" />

      <!--      <bean class="org.lacare.frc.controller.ApplicationsController">
        <property name="formView" value="applications" />
        <property name="successView" value="CustomerSuccess" />
       </bean> -->
       <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
          <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
         <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
         </bean>



<mvc:view-controller path="/search" view-name="search.jsp"/>
```

My web.xml looks like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app ... version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>png</extension>
        <mime-type>image/png</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener- class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
          /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

I tried the following as well

But I get an error when I try to run the application. search.jsp should be shown as the default page. Error 403--Forbidden From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol HTTP/1.1: 10.4.4 403 Forbidden The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.

Answer (score 7):

You should use

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/search" view-name="search"/>
```

The view name is search, and only then your `InternalResourceViewResolver` with the configuration,

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
     <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
     <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
 </bean>
```

will resolve it to  the jsp by prefixing with `/WEB-INF/view/` end suffixing it with `.jsp`

In web.xml change servlet mapping to

```
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I tried this. But I get a following error when I try to run the application. search.jsp should be shown as the default page.      Error 403--Forbidden                                             From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol  HTTP/1.1:
10.4.4 403 Forbidden

The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity.

Comment: My guess is that you have some additional configurations not shown above. Maybe Spring security or other security related configurations in web.xml

Comment: I added my web.xml above. Please let me know. I am using weblogic server 11g. search.jsp is at /WEB-INF/view/   location

Comment: I had a  <welcome-file-list> in the web.xml and I removed it now. After that  Error 403--Forbidden error is gone. Now I have a Error 404--Not Found error which is a progress. in the browser I hit following URL - http://localhost:8080/MYApplicationName/

Comment: Why don't you double check of folder name view or views